# how to turn a vector into a set in r

Tags: r

I would like to see a list of all the possible values, without repetition, in a column of a data frame.  Something like:

```
as.set(series["begin_year"][,1])
```

for the column "begin_year" although `as.set` doesn't exist.

Comment: Will `unique()` get the job done?  Or, if column is a factor, `levels()`?  Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @jthetzel, make it answer ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`unique()` [or `levels()`, if the column is a factor].

Here's the reproducible example:

```
dat <- OrchardSprays
dat$rowpos
unique(dat$rowpos)
dat$treatment
unique(dat$treatment)
levels(dat$treatment)
```

**EDIT**
Note that `levels()` will return unique levels of the factor, even if the level is unused.  Consider:

```
dat2 <- subset(dat, treatment != "A")
unique(dat2$treatment)
# [1] D E B H G F C
# Levels: A B C D E F G H
levels(dat2$treatment) 
# [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H"
```

You can get rid of the unused levels with `droplevels()`:

```
dat2$treatment <- droplevels(dat2$treatment)
levels(dat2$treatment)
# [1] "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H"
```

Comment: A good thing to note here is that the word "set" is used strictly to work with algebraic set theory functions.  You really only needed a vector here so far as I can tell, which is why `unique` and `levels` is the way to go.

Comment: <pedantic> It's not *algebraic* set theory.  It's just (elementary) set theory.  </pedantic>  :)  There's a field of algebraic set theory, but the intersection with relevant R functions, minus those relevant to set theory, is...

Answer (score 5):

The *unique* function should do this, and there's also a few other set-related functions: union, intersect, setdiff, setequal and is.element that are documented on the help(union) page.